# How can I get a reference to the NSOperationQueue from an NSOperation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Is there a way to get the "parent" operation queue that the nsoperation is inside, from that same nsoperation? Something like [self getCurrentOperationQueue].

Comment: "getters" in Objective C tend not to have the "get" prefix they do in Java, et al.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the current queue by calling the appropriately named [`+[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSOperationQueue/currentQueue) from inside the running operation.

> **currentQueue** 
>   Returns the operation queue that launched the current
>   operation.
>
> *+ (id)currentQueue* 
>   
>   **Return Value**
>   The operation queue that started the operation or nil if the queue could not be determined.
>
> **Discussion** 
>   You can use this method from within a running operation
>   object to get a reference to the operation queue that started it.
>   Calling this method from outside the context of a running operation
>   typically results in nil being returned.

Answer (score 3):

[[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004592-RH2-SW20)